# Why it is not possible to get exact solution for cubic potential perturbation in 1D SHO and we have to use perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory, approximations

For $x$ and $x^2$ we get exact solution easily without applying perturbation theory, but I read that above order perturbation can not be solved exactly. Can anyone explain clearly why?

Comment: why would you expect an exact solution in terms of "simple" functions?  Plenty of differential equations (in fact the majority of differential equations) do not have solutions expressible in terms of such "elementary" functions.

Comment: Related: [How to obtain large order perturbation series for cubic anharmonic oscillator?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/555691/2451)