# Why it is not possible to get exact solution for cubic potential perturbation for 1D SHO and we have to use perturbation theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory, approximations, anharmonic-oscillators

Can anyone help me in providing the process of finding exact solution in case of cubic perturbation in 1D SHO, or any suitable resource?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why it is not possible to get exact solution for cubic potential perturbation in 1D SHO and we have to use perturbation theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/534680/)

Comment: Hi RISHAV SAGAR. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because the linked duplicate has been deleted and is, therefore, in general not accessible.