# Computing stationary states with the path integral method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, path-integral

Fourier transform has been used to determine eigenstates with path integral method also in [Journal of Mathematical Physics, 59(5), [052104]](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5028503) ([pdf](https://tutcris.tut.fi/portal/files/21205260/Eigenstates_and_dynamics_of_Hookes_atom_2018.pdf)).
Suppose we have a stationary system with Hamiltonian eigenstates $f_k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and energies $E_k$.
Let
$$\Psi(x,0) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k f_k(x)$$
and assume that $\Psi(x,0)$ is normed.
Now
$$\Psi(x,t) = \sum_k \exp(-i E_k t) c_k f_k(x)$$
Let $g(t) := \Psi(x_0,t)$ for some fixed point $x_0$.
Now
$$\hat{g}(\omega) = \sqrt{2\pi} \sum_k c_k f_k(x_0) \delta(\omega+E_k)$$
where the unitary definition of the Fourier transform is used. So in principle we should see the energies of the eigenstates from the Fourier spectrum of $g$. We can also get the coefficients $c_k$ and functions $f_k$ from the heights of the delta peaks in $\hat{g}(\omega)$ and normalization of the functions $f_k$.

So far I have tested that this method gives correct energies for the harmonic oscillator. Any comments about this method?

Comment: If you like this question, you may also enjoy reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/555691/2451) Phys.SE post.