# Why is the series solution for the SHO from the TISE valid for very large displacement from the equilibrium?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation

Why is it that the SHO/SHM solution
$$u(x)=H(x)\,e^{-x^2/2},\quad \Psi(x,t)=u(x)\,e^{-iEt/\hbar}$$
with $$H_n (x)=\sum_k^na_kx^k \tag{Hermite Polynomials}$$
is valid even when $x$ (displacement from equilibrium) becomes very large, in which case $H_n(x) \propto x^n$?

Isn't the Taylor expansion of the potential $$V(x_0+\delta x)\approx V(x_0)+\left.\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2V}{dx^2}\right|_{x_0}(\delta x)^2$$  only valid for when $\delta x$ is small?

Comment: The SHO is defined as the system for which Hooke's law is exact.

Comment: @Connor Of course it is, but the OP is asking, broadly, how the asymptotics of SHO solutions mesh with  larger excursions  from equilibrium in an imperfectly harmonic potential!

Comment: Is [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/555691/how-to-obtain-large-order-perturbation-series-for-cubic-anharmonic-oscillator) what you are asking?

Comment: In all fairness, the wavefunction never becomes very large, by dint of the suppression of the exponential prefactor.  Large-x regions contribute very little to the energy, etc., as you might check.

Answer (score 2):

There are no approximations made in this solution.

The potential is exactly a quadratic. So, in the simple quantum harmonic oscillator system, you don't need to do the expansion of the potential you mention at the end of your question; it simply *is* exactly a quadratic.

There can be some confusion because people often say things like "this dip in X funny-looking potential is quadratic for small deviations from the middle of the dip," but the QHO is in an exactly quadratic potential, so it looks quadratic arbitrarily far from the middle.

Comment: But.. how is discussion of the SHO going to address the question which is about departures from harmonicity?

Comment: I did not interpret the question that way. OP explicitly says "in the SHO system."

Comment: No, he is *not* restricting his problem to the SHO: why bother asking anything there? He is asking *why* he is allowed to apply SHO solutions extending to large distances to the small excursions dictated by his TISE proximation.

Comment: I guess we'll have to hear from OP, but I did not interpret the question that way. The answer seems trivial to "experts", but these types of confusions (specifically, not recognizing when one needs to make the approximation given in the question and what its effects are) are common for students. That is why someone might "bother asking anything there."